# 1,5,9,13,17...Is a sequence with inf many primes. How to show using Gaussian integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I decided to take the product of each term in the sequence and add I to the result. My main issue is that I do not know how to show that this resulting number must have a Gaussian prime factor q which has a Split primagon. If I can show this, then my idea was to show that q*q' is a prime integer within the sequence where q' is the conjugate of q.

Showing the product has a Gaussian prime factor isn't difficult, but I'm not sure how to how it's split, nor am I sure why only the split case allows for q*q' to produce a prime within the sequence.

Comment: My goal was to utilize Gaussian integers in the proof

Comment: Refer https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/math5230f12/handouts/Zinotes.pdf

You might get some ideas from here.